# How can I connect my Django application to AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use django-elasticsearch-dsl to connect my Django app to AWS Elasticsearch. I went through the documentation at https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, but all I found was how to connect to Elasticsearch on localhost.

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL={
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200'
    },
}
```

What configuration do I have to add to connect my Django application to AWS Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

```
OPENSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': [{
            "host": "search-your-domain.eu-north-1.es.amazonaws.com",
            "port": 443,
        }],
        'http_auth': ("master-login", "master-password"),
    },
}
```